# Different models for prediction when sequential data is given

Tags: algorithm, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, regression, prediction

I'm trying to predict stock prices for the next month ( maybe year) given sequential for 10 years that passed. What are some good models for this task?

I'm thinking about :

1) Recurrent neural network (long short term memory)

1') If anyone can give me a good resource / implementation for this is appreciated ( and by this i refer to algorithm coding, not just import some libraries and build the network in like 5 lines of code, i need the whole logic )

2) Linear regression (not sure if this is ok)

I need some other suggestions, and if the mentioned ones are ok for the task.

P.S. I'm a noob in deep-learning, artificial-intelligence.

Comment: There are no good models for this, because A) stuff happens, and B) the government keeps changing the rules.

Comment: @user3386109 come on man if we are talking like that then a big part of deep-learning is not useful, because your points A) and B). Then suppose bad stuff doesn't happen and the government doesn't change the rules.

Comment: Ok, then your deep learning algorithm has to have the appropriate inputs, which would be a lot more than just historical pricing data. It needs to analyze the annual reports for one-off charges and profits. It needs all of the applicable changes to the tax laws and government regulations. It needs to look at inflation data, and supply and demand. The list goes on and on. So yeah, if your deep learning code can understand what drove the prices changes in the past, it can separate the false gains/losses from the true gains/losses, and make a prediction that will be correct until stuff happens.